# How to set multiple ParentalKeys to Wagtail TaggedItemBase tag class

Tags: python, django, wagtail, django-taggit, wagtail-snippet

I have two different page models (no subclassing, separate apps with only similar fields being common ones like "model name", "id", "parts") , let's say, cars and motorcycles. I'm making a separate page with a table of their parts (which also needs to contain columns like "id" which i assume can be a pk,"web store link", and "used by" which will show all Bike and Car models that use the part); 
Since they can share a few of the same parts, I want for them to be connected to the same Tag model (instead of having "CarPageTag" and "BikePageTag");
What I've tried so far :

- I tried to make a separate app for "parts". I figured how to include that class from other app and it works with either car or motorcycle, but not both, because of this error:

AssertionError: ParentalKey(['CarsBlogApp.CarDetailPage',
   'BikesBlogApp.BikeDetailPage']) is invalid. First parameter to
   ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'

- I had a simple solution working in plain Django app via ManyToManyField (but I need the wagtail autofill tag selection page in admin)
- I looked all over django, wagtail and taggit docs
- I looked through all youtube tutorials

Edit: adding models.py ***the way I thought It'll work:***

**PartsApp/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase

class PartsPage(Page):

    templates = "parts/parts_page.html"
    subpage_types = []
    max_count = 1
    parent_page_type = ['home.HomePage']
    paragraph = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text='Overwrites the default title',
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("paragraph"),
    ]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Needed supplies Page"
        verbose_name_plural = "Needed supplies Pages"

class PartTagPage(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey(
        ['CarApp.CarDetailPage','BikeApp.BikeDetailPage'],
        related_name='tagged_items',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

And **CarsApp/models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from blocks import blocks
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase
from PartsApp.models import PartTagPage

class CarListingPage(Page):
    template = "CarsApp/car_listing_page.html"
    subpage_types = ['CarsApp.CarDetailPage']
    parent_page_type = ['home.HomePage']
    max_count = 1
    paragraph = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text='Overwrites the default title',
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("paragraph"),
    ]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        all_cars = CarsDetailPage.objects.live().public().order_by('-first_published_at')

        if request.GET.get('tag', None):
            tags = request.GET.get('tag')
            all_cars = all_cars.filter(tags__slug__in=[tags])

        context["cars"] = all_animals
        return context

class CarDetailPage(Page):
    subpage_types = []
    parent_page_types = ['CarsApp.CarsListingPage']
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through='PartsApp.PartTagPage', blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    model = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    car_image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        related_name="+",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("model"),
        FieldPanel("name"),
        FieldPanel("description"),
        FieldPanel("tags"),
        ImageChooserPanel("car_image"),
    ]
```

The **BikesApp/models.py is pretty much the same.**
Again, **these do not work.**

Comment: Your `ParentalKey` definition isn't right.  Just like `ForeignKey`, `ParentalKey` can only point to one model.  Without seeing more of what you're trying to do (you should post your `models.py`), it's hard to help, but if you had `ManyToManyField` working in plain Django, then you might need Wagtail's `ParentalManyToManyField`:  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/releases/1.9.html?highlight=parentalmanytomanyfield#many-to-many-relations-on-page-models

Comment: @DanSwain thank you, I added my models.py.
Sorry I'm relatively new to programming in general as well as python, django and wagtail, so my questions may sound facepalm-y, but:
it seems like ParentalManyToManyField is for categories, not tags? I need the admin functionality to have pretty wagtail autocomplete picker\deleter but also to have a popup for filling additional tag fields like in simplest django.

Answer (score 4):

Setting up separate `CarPageTag` and `BikePageTag` models *is* the solution you want (assuming they're subclasses of `TaggedItemBase`, [as per the pattern shown in the Wagtail documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#tagging)).

`TaggedItemBase` is not a tag model itself - it just defines the relation between the page model and the tag model (which, in this case, is `taggit.Tag`, the standard tag model provided as default by the django-taggit library). Therefore, `CarPageTag` is setting up a relation between `CarPage` and `taggit.Tag`, and `BikePageTag` is setting up a relation between `BikePage` and `taggit.Tag` - both are using the same tag model.

If you *did* want cars and bikes to maintain their own independent set of tags, you'd need a different pattern - [custom tag models](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#custom-tag-models).

Comment: thank you, this helps with understanding, but it seems like it does not solve the problem without further metaprogramming (else, how do I give tags fields ?) I explained this better [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61782154/additional-fields-associated-with-wagtail-tags)